# Unable to build Azure Storage SDK without SLF4J

Tags: java, android, azure, azure-blob-storage

I took the Library source code directly from https://github.com/azure/azure-storage-java for android

Added the code to my existing library project. Everything seems fine expect that it gives errors in files like OperationContext.java asking me to import org.slf4j.Logger

From the documentation it is clear that the library is optional. Why then should I use the library, is there anyway to build this library without the use of SLF4J library?

Do i have to modify the source code to build it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for the Azure Storage Android Client Library, it is located at https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-android and not the location you linked.

Adding the Android source code to your existing library project should be successful without any modifications.

Comment: Yes this was the issue, the android library is very recent but most MS Official documentation points to the JAVA Library and not to the Android one.